# Preventing solvent evaporation for small scale synthesis

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, synthesis

I have been conducting an organic synthesis with quite expensive starting material, so whenever I setup the reaction I only use 0.1 g of starting material. I use 4 mL of toluene to adjust the concentration of the starting material to about 0.1 M (although it is not essential option). I use 25 mL three-necked flask, sealed with a rubber septum, a glass stopper, and a reflux condensor. Top of the reflux condensor is connected with oil bubbler. So it is a closed system. I usually apply Teflon tape at the glass joint. Although this condition is generally okay, sometimes the solvent is completely evaporated during dawn. I searched for the alternatives, and I found someone that recommends glass thick wall pressure tubes or microwaves vial which don't require a condensor. Can I use these for alternatives, or anyone have recommendations? To be honest, I am hesitating to use grease because of the potential contamination.

- additional question : Do the rubber septa assure more tight sealings than glass stoppers?

Comment: Your system is far from closed.  Are you adding reactants or sampling? Look up the composition of the rubber. You do not mention the other reactant[s]. Possibilities are better matching of the joints, reducing the number of joints, getting rid of the septum and the Teflon. You do not mention analysis. If it is spectrometric consider running the reactions in temperature controlled cells, uses less material and eliminates a transfer. If a solvent is needed try sealed tube reactions but practice before committing the expensive reactants. [In any case some practice on knowns is a good idea.]

Comment: Why do you need to reflux?  Why not use a higher-boiling solvent and better temperature control?

Comment: I have used a sealed microwave vial in a heating block successfully in similar circumstances